# Using checkboxes and required with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried to use the html5 `required` attribute for my group of checkboxes but I don't find a nice way to implement it with ng-form.

When a checkbox is checked I want the value of that input-element to be pushed to an array of values.

The angular required validator seems to watch the ng-model associated with the input element, but how can I link several checkboxes to the same model and update it's value with the value of the input field?

Right now the implementation is like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tryggve/thbkA/).

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ng-form name="myForm">
    <span ng-repeat="choice in choices">
      <label class="checkbox" for="{{choice.id}}">
        <input type="checkbox" required="required" value="{{choice.id}}" ng-click="updateQuestionValue(choice)" ng-model="choice.checked" name="group-one" id="{{choice.id}}" />
        {{choice.label}}
      </label>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" ng-click="submitSurvey(survey)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" />
  </ng-form>
</div>​
```

The updateQuestionValue-function handles the adding or removing from the array of values but each checkbox has it's own model and that is why each checkbox needs to be checked in order for the form to be valid.

I've got it to work on a group of radio buttons, but they all work on the same model as only one can be selected.

Comment: I banged my head against a wall for an hour with this using Angular v1.2.1 until trying it on 1.2.10.  Seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want the submit button disabled if no choice is selected the easiest way is to check the length of the array in the ng-disabled attribute, without setting the required attribute

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" ng-click="submitSurvey(survey)" 
 ng-disabled="value.length==0" />
```

[See here for updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thbkA/2/)

Another way to do this would be to check the array length in the ng-required attribute of the checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{choice.id}}" ng-click="updateQuestionValue(choice)"
  ng-model="choice.checked" name="group-one" id="{{choice.id}}" 
  ng-required="value.length==0" />
```

[Second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thbkA/4/)

Comment: Thanks! I went with your second solution to fix this problem for now.

Comment: `ng-required` solution is very easy to implement, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A few things:

- I would go with an approach that just updated the entire array in this case, as it would simplify the code a little. (You might not want to do this if you're doing anything stateful with the $scope.value array contents, but it doesn't look like you are).
- you can just use `<form>` rather than `<ng-form>`.
- move the submit function off of the button's `ng-click` and into the form's `ng-submit`. This makes validation management a little easier with angular's built-in validation (if you care about that)
- If your `<label>` wraps your `<input>` you don't need the `for=""` attribute.

[Here is an updated fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/tjP8S/2/)

And here's the code:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitSurvey(survey)">
        <span ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" required="required" value="{{choice.id}}" ng-change="updateQuestionValues()" ng-model="choice.checked" name="group-one" />
                {{choice.label}}
            </label>
        </span>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" />
    </form>
    {{value}}
</div>​
```

JS

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.choices = [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": "1",
        "label": "Good"},
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "2",
        "label": "Ok"},
    {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "3",
        "label": "Bad"}];

    $scope.value = [];

    $scope.updateQuestionValues = function() {
        $scope.value = _.filter($scope.choices, function(c) {
            return c.checked;
        });
    };
}​
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your thoughts, I will refactor my final implementation. But I don't see how this helps me with my initial problem? I still need to get all three checkboxes checked before `myForm.$invalid == false`

Answer (score 5):

I just added a hidden input with ng-model that's the same as your ng-model for the radio button:

```
 <div class="radio" ng-repeat="option in item.AnswerChoices | orderBy: DisplayOrder">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="item.Answer" name="mulchoice" value="{{option.DisplayName}}" />
        <span>{{option.DisplayName}}</span>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="item.Answer" name="hiddenradiobuttoninput" required/>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution! I improved it a little by using `ng-true-value="'I Agree'" ng-false-value=""` on the checkbox. This way, if they check, then uncheck, the form will revert back to being invalid. (without adding this, the user can check the box, and then uncheck it, and the value of the hidden becomes "false" which is technically valid value for required hidden field.)

Comment: oops just realized your answer is using `radio` instead of `checkbox`. My improvement is only valid for `checkbox`

Answer (score 2):

Why not make your checkbox models the array

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value[$index]" value="{{choice.id}}/>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thbkA/1/

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution but it still doesn't help with my initial problem that in order to make Angular mark my form as valid I need to make all three checkboxes checked.

Comment: @Tryggve, checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289248/bind-json-object-to-radio-button-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul  class="list-group">
  <li ng-repeat='animal in animals' class="list-group-item">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
        ng-model="xyx"
        ng-click="toggleAnimal(animal)"
        ng-checked="selectedAnimals.indexOf(animal) > -1"
        ng-required="selectedAnimals.length == 0" /> 
        {{animal}}</label>
  </li>                  
</ul>

$scope.toggleAnimal = function(animal){
    var index = $scope.selectedAnimals.indexOf(animal);
    if(index == -1) {
      $scope.selectedAnimals.push(animal);
    }
    else{
      $scope.selectedAnimals.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

See the full detail and [demo and other related examples](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1222/angularjs-checkboxlist-required-validation-with-demo)