# AngularJS required radio buttons needs two click events to be valid

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple form where a radio button is required to be selected in order for a form to be valid. The radio buttons are generated by `ngRepeat`.

As you can see from this fiddle, while the desired behavior is that when the radio button is clicked for the first time, that should validate the form (being the only element), however notice that it takes an additional click (on the same radio button or any other) to validate the form:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xsk5X/3/

What am I missing?

Comment: It becomes more crazy if look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FQRD7/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yep, it's almost as if there needs to be some view binding in order to "resolve" the state of the validation

Comment: i dont know the reason  but if you just keep  one item in the array it works fine

Comment: This works with angular 1.0.2 and brakes in 1.0.3. Since there were quite a few changes in [1.0.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#103-bouncy-thunder-2012-11-26) that could cause this, I suggest you open an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues).

Comment: This seems more of a hack but if you add `ng-click=""` to the input, it seems to force a digest and update your form: http://jsfiddle.net/XfAHe/

Comment: @PaulSmith can you mark Preston Badeer's answer as correct for others that come across this?  It's the correct solution, I just verified it.  It's also the answer with the most upvotes.  Daniel's answer might work but it's a hack. 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the ng-click attribute to your radio button input.

Credit to Manny D for noting this first. Yes, this is a little hackish, but it works. E.g.,

```
<input type="radio" 
       name="groupName"  
       ng-model="editObject.Property"                             
       ng-value="someValue"
       ng-click />
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33295625/4534064. It worked for me.

Answer (score 40):

**All the other solutions are work-arounds:** All you have to do is remove the `name` attribute, when you use the `ng-model` attribute you don't need it and they conflict.

Specifying the `name` causes Angular to get confused because it changes the value once for the angular model and another time for the form element name.

Comment: Wow thanks, this fixed my problem. Couldn't see anything about this in the docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because a colleague had copied the radio buttons in the same page and hidden them for  temporary reference, so duplicate radio inputs with the same name

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is breaking - is because you're setting all radio boxes to be required. As a result, depending on how you write it - angularjs is saying it's invalid because not all have been selected at some point.

The way around this is to do something like the following:

[Using checkboxes and required with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567235/using-checkboxes-and-required-with-angularjs)

(check the 1st and 2nd answers). This will resolve your problem.

Comment: Additionally - try updating angularjs. They're up to 1.0.5 now, so it might be worthwhile updating to see if there's a simpler solution now.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I wasn't requiring any radio boxes and still had this issue.

Comment: Tbh, this is over 2 years old. It may not apply anymore. Angular JS has moved a lot since then (it was at 0.8 I believe at the time of this writing).

Comment: I think I found a fix for the latest version, added my answer to the mix.

Comment: see comment above ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an AngularJS 1.0.3 $scope.$apply update problem.
Tested your exact Fiddle in 1.0.2 (check it out yourself) and it works the way you expect it too.

It doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with your code, just that $scope.$apply(or $digest) isn't working as expected on the first select.

A very simple fix is to force the $scope to also update on every select, try changing the following line of code in your form:

```
<p>Favorite Beatle</p>
```

change it too:

```
<p>Favorite Beatle: {{name}}</p>
```

And you will see how myForm.$invalid is updated even after the first click.

I would try it out with the latest AngularJs version and let us know if that happens there too.
Another solution I can think of it setting the default selected radio, which will cause myForm.$invalid to be false from the beginning. you can do this by adding the following line in your controller code:

```
$scope.name = "John";
```

or any default name you want.

Answer (score 1):

Some times the $digest cycle dosen't $apply(fn) because you have two o more instances.
For fix this you need $apply this trick manually, so put this in your directives:

```
angular.('myApp',[])
.directive('ngRadioExtend', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
                iElm.bind('click', function(){
                    $rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply()
                });
            }
        };
    }])
```

and use it as:

```
<input type="radio" name="input_name" ng-model="some" value="F" ng-required="true" ng-radio-extend>

<input type="radio" name="input_name" ng-model="some" value="M" ng-required="true" ng-radio-extend>
```

DONE it's the correct way!

Comment: This works fine! Just voted for it. But it still feels like a workaround for something that AngularJS *should* be able to resolve by itself.

Comment: I agree with you, I hope help someone! Thanks!

Comment: well, I just manage to make it work by wrapping the `$apply` call in a timeout: `setTimeout( function() { $rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply(); })`

Comment: I think this is expensive in dirty check time, but if you don't have a complicated UI go ahead with $apply. The correct way for do it easy is do something really simple: put your scope like $scope.some as $scope.some = { something : "somevalue" }; done!

Comment: Don't use `$rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply()` - it's always been a hack and is already deprecated in recent version (will result in an error)

Comment: Manually re-applying scope is never "the correct way." This is a bad example for new Angular users.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the scope not getting updated still occurs in 1.1.5

A simple work around is to just add
    `<span ng-show="false"> {{name}} </span>`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonyschak/xaQJH/

Answer (score 0):

For IONIC v1,
add `name=""` to prevent ionic auto-generate attribute `name`.
Then, I can change the selected item with only one click.

```
<ion-radio class="label-ticket" 
    ng-repeat="topic in vm.listTopic track by $index"
    ng-value="topic"
    ng-model="vm.topicSupport"
    name="">
    {{ topic.title }}
</ion-radio>
```