# AngularJs radio button dirty validation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two fields , for email the validation is working fine , but for radio button no error is been shown .. i am not getting this , why this is happening . i ma using angular-1.0.8.min.js

```
 //js code 
    var app = angular.module("App", []);
    app.controller('signupController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.selectedGender = '';
          $scope.gender = [{'name':'Male', 'id':1}, {'name':'Female', 'id':2}];

          $scope.submitted = true;
          $scope.signupForm = function() {
            if ($scope.signup_form.$valid) {
              // Submit as normal
            } else {
              $scope.signup_form.submitted = true;
            }
          }
        }]);
     //html code  
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
    <body ng-app="validationExampleApp">
    <div align="center" style="width: 500px; ">
    <form  ng-controller="signupController"  name="signup_form" novalidate ng-submit="signupForm()">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Signup</legend>

        <div class="row">          
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <label>Your email</label>
        <input type="email" 
          placeholder="Email" 
          name="email" 
          ng-model="signup.email" 
          ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20 required />
        <div class="error" 
             ng-show="signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.email.$invalid && signup_form.submitted ">
          <small class="error" 
                 ng-show="signup_form.email.$error.required">
                 Your email is required.
          </small>

          <small class="error" 
                 ng-show="signup_form.email.$error.email">
                 That is not a valid email. Please input a valid email.
          </small>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
          <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in gender">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="signup.selectedGender" name="radiob" id="{{val.id}}" value="{{val.id}}"  ng-click  required /> {{val.name}}
      </div>
      <div class="error" 
             ng-show="signup_form.radiob.$dirty && signup_form.radiob.$invalid && signup_form.submitted ">
          <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.radiob.$error.required">
                 Your email is required.
          </small>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button radius">Submit</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: This is very crucial point. Please help me also.

Comment: create a plunker demo that replicates issue

Comment: I made a JSFiddle about it one day, may be it can help you to understand how form validation works : http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4088/ (sorry some text data are in french..)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell for sure because the code provided is invalid but you are probably hitting the angular js bug where it doesn't mark the radio button as valid until all radio buttons have been selected.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778739/angularjs-required-radio-buttons-needs-two-click-events-to-be-valid)

This is fixed in version 1.2.0-rc.3. I've created a Plunker demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GRSYS4SpdfsAd89E9vyX?p=preview) with some code changes to mimic what I think you are trying to do.