# Angularjs, checking if radio buttons in form have been selected

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

I'm starting with AngularJS, and I'm building a multi-step form where user has to fill different pages. When finished a page, he's allowed to press a next button and fill the following page.

For the first page, I've built in the HMTL a form (named `pageOneForm`), with different text input fields, marked as `required`, and in the relative controller I'm doing this watch:

```
$scope.$watch('pageOneForm.$valid', function(validity) {
      ModelData.actualPageCompleted = validity;
})
```

And it works like a charme. My model (`ModelData`) is updated.

I was trying to apply the same logic to the following part of the app, the second page. Instead of input text, the user has to select two options from 2 different radio buttons groups.
 So I built in the html a list of buttons via `ng-repeat` :

```
<div ng-Controller="PageTwo" ng-show='data.actualPage == 2'>
    <form  name="pageTwoForm">
        <h3>General Information > Knowledge About </h3>
        <div>
        <b>User</b>
        <div ng-repeat="option in userOptions">
            <input type="radio" name="userGroups" ng-model="data.knowledgeAboutUser" ng-value="option.id" id="{{option.id}}" required>{{option.text}}
        </div>


        <div ng-repeat="option in targetGroupUserOptions">
            <input type="radio" name = "targetUserGroup" ng-model="data.knowledgeAboutTargetGroup" ng-value="option.id" id="{{option.id}}" required>{{option.text}}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and I've implemented the same code as above in its controller:

```
$scope.$watch('pageTwoForm.$valid', function(validity) {
      ModelData.actualPageCompleted = validity;
})
```

but apparently it doesn't work, and in my model `actualPageCompleted` is always true...
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: did you try to "watch" the variable, so that when it changes, you know you got a new value?

Answer (score 1):

I did my best to create a controller with some dummy data to get a fiddle working with your example code. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/2MpWf/) You need to force the $digest cycle to update your form's validity state on ng-click for the radio buttons (see [this SO post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778739/angularjs-required-radio-buttons-needs-two-click-events-to-be-valid)), which is why the method

```
    $scope.forceDigest = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ $rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply(); });
    };
```

is necessary. Alternatively, you can get rid of the method call and uncomment the html code

```
    <h3 ng-show="false">{{data.knowledgeAboutTargetGroup}}</h3>
    <h3 ng-show="false">{{data.knowledgeAboutUser}}</h3>
```

in the fiddle to force the form object to update as well.

And I would make sure that `ModelData.actualPageCompleted` is not retaining its true value from when `pageOneForm.$valid` became true and it was set.

I hope that this helps!