# Angular Radio Button Form Validation Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a function that updates after each form field is changed. However with radio buttons, the form state isn't valid until I either change the radio button twice, or change a different field. Even more, when I console log the form object I can see that the radio group is indeed valid.

The HTML

```
 <div ng-controller="formController">
  <form name="testForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" required ng-change="updateForm(testForm)">
    <ng-form name="radioGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" required="!sex" ng-model="sex" value="male" ng-change="updateForm(testForm)"/> Male
      <input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" required="!sex" ng-model="sex" value="female" ng-change="updateForm(testForm)"/> Female
    </ng-form>
  </form>

  <div ng-show="testForm.$dirty">
    Form Dirty
  </div>
  <div ng-show="isFormDirty">
    From Dirty from controller
  </div>
  <div ng-show="testForm.$valid">
    Form Valid
  </div>
    <div ng-show="isFormValid">
    From Valid from controller
  </div>
</div>
```

And Javascript

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('formController', function($scope)         {
      $scope.hello = 'hello from controller';
      $scope.name = null;
      $scope.sex = null;
      $scope.isFormDirty = null;
      $scope.isFormValid = null;

      $scope.updateForm = function(form) {

        if(form.name.$dirty || form.radioGroup.$dirty) {
          $scope.isFormDirty = true;
        }

        if(form.name.$valid && form.radioGroup.$valid) {
          $scope.isFormValid = true;
        }

      }
    });
```

I've also created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gGYKBQKEb3TsMxBeh1Yy?p=preview) so you can see what I'm talking about. Any insight into this problem would be a great help.

Comment: The required attribute is boolean attribute, you can't use `required="!sex"`. Removing this also solves your validity issue.

Comment: Removing the required="!sex" and replacing it with required does not solve the issue. The steps to recreate the issue I'm experiencing are: enter some text into the text box. the form is now dirty and the controller can see that. Then enter a selection into the radio. The form is valid, however the controller doesn't see that. Changing the radio selection or updating the text box will update the form again so the controller can see its valid. Take a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/daAxHdbUojLjGZCWmrI9) plunk with the updated required attribute.

Comment: looks like issue with radio button binding take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778739/angularjs-required-radio-buttons-needs-two-click-events-to-be-valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my specific problem by wrapping my call to `$scope.updateForm` in a timeout. I know it's probably not the best solution but it works for my purposes

```
  $scope.callTimeout = function(form) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.updateForm(form);
    }, 0)
  }
```

And then

```
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" required ng-model="sex" value="male" ng-change="callTimeout(testForm)" ng-click/> Male
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" required ng-model="sex" value="female" ng-change="callTimeout(testForm)" ng-click/> Female
```

*Also* this is just a demo of a much larger project that I'm working on. I'm not using `$scope.updateForm` to actually check the forms validation for user messages, I'm only checking `$dirty` and `$valid` in this case to update a progress bar for the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are checkin the validity of your form with `ng-change="updateForm(testForm)"`. And `ng-change` is triggered before the Angular validation form process occurs. That is why you can see in  `console.log($scope.testForm)` the form being valid and not at the execution.

To debug more easily your form, I suggest to use :

```
<pre>{{ testForm.$valid | json }}</pre>
```

Angular will show you the "live state" of your form.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the form's validation to fire within updateForm?

Comment: I don't think so because it is not a recommended approach with Angular forms : binding is better than triggering IMHO.