# Bind JSON object to radio button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

So I am trying to bind radio buttons to objects. I have spent like an hour trying to figure this up and at last admit defeat. Here's what I got:

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="theCustomer in customers">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="currentCustomer" value="theCustomer" id="{{theCustomer.id}}" ng-change="currentCustomer = theCustomer">
                <label for="{{theCustomer.id}}">{{theCustomer.name}}</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The angular stuff:

```
bankApp.controller("BankController", function ($scope, CustomerRepository)
{
    $scope.customers = [];
    $scope.currentCustomer = {};
    
    $scope.createCustomer = function () {
        CustomerRepository.save($scope.customer, function (customer) {
            $scope.customers.push(customer);
            $scope.customer = {};
        });
    };
});
```

Currently, when I try and click on a radio button nothing happens, it doesn't even get checked. I'm sure there's got to be a really simple solution to this. The end goal is to have `currentCustomer` hold the customer reflected in the radio selection.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.currentCustomer" name="foo" ng-value="theCustomer" id="{{theCustomer.id}}">{{theCustomer.name}}</td>
```

The key here is the `ng-value="theCustomer`. This is how angular knows which object is selected. The html `value` only knows string values and cannot map to objects.

If you insert the above code, the radio will reflect the model, even if it is changed programatically. Also, you can't forget the `$parent` in the ng-model because the `ng-repeat` creates a new scope.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, getting a radio group to work inside an ng-repeat can be a bit tricky.  The issue is with the ng-repeat creating its own child scope.  One solution is to bind the model to the $parent.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775981/angularjs-using-ng-repeat-to-create-sets-of-radio-inputs) gives an example.

I also created a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigbiff02/uNFWW/) that more closely resembles your example.

In essence, I think your html is the only point that needs reworking:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="theCustomer in customers">
    <td><input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.currentCustomer" name="foo" value="{{theCustomer}}" id="{{theCustomer.id}}">{{theCustomer.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So this works mostly, the only problem is `currentCustomer` is being set as stringified json rather than the object. Is there an easy fix for this? I tried doing it without the double braces and that didnt work.

Comment: What do you wish the final result to look like exactly?

Comment: I actually figured it out. The value attribute only takes a string and cant handle an object. I refactored to accommodate this. Thanks!

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey Can you post the refactored code? How are you able to set the default selected radio button? http://jsfiddle.net/uNFWW/31/

Comment: @Tushar see me answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the scope inheritance, you can read more about the problem [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance).

One solution that I use in such a case, is to bind the object to an object property instead of a primitive value like `ng-model="form.currentCustomer"`.

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0VJ5c6BcvO0OwEf0KiN0?p=preview)